# What is the best practice for conditional if statements in a mySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form that is used to filter search criteria in a user table.
In ColdFusion I would just write:

```
select * from  tbl.users where 1 = 1   
<cfif form.firstname NEQ ''>
    AND firstname LIKE '%#form.firstname#%'
</cfif> 
<cfif form.lastname NEQ ''>
    AND lastname LIKE '%#form.lastname#%'
</cfif> 
<cfif form.useremail NEQ ''>
    AND useremail LIKE '%#form.useremail#%'
</cfif>
```

(All form variables would be sanitized, of course)

The best I can come up with in PHP is:

```
$myString = '';

$firstName  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstName']);
if (empty($firstName)) {
}else{
    $myString .=  " AND firstName LIKE '%$firstName%'" ;
}
$lastName  =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastName']);
if (empty($lastName)) {
}else{
    $myString .=  " AND lastName LIKE '%$lastName%'" ;
}
```

Then:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tbl.Users_new WHERE 1=1 $myString" ;
```

But, I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Anyone have a better way?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: And try `if ( ! empty($firstName)) {` rather than coding an empty IF with an ELSE

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's the first thing I noticed ;-)

Comment: The code is for discussion only, it's not code used in production. All inputs would be sanitized before finalizing.

Comment: looks good to me. i use the same pattern of including the space *before* the AND, right where and when its needed, not having other parts of the code remember to tack on extra a trailing space that might or might not be needed. Otherwise, just opinion based style differences. Getting more advanced, keep in mind the difference in precedence between AND and OR, and parens to override that. (Note that mysqli_real_escape_string is safe from SQL Injection as long as the connection is using a known safe characterset, but best practice is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders.)

Comment: Things like this are very easy to implement with a nice framework using active record.